# 8 math books, 7 computer science books and 5 history books(combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics

On a past exam paper I have the following problem.

**On a bookshelf there are 8 math books, 7 computer science books and 5 history books.
How many ways can one pick two books from different fields**

What formula should one use?
I have done it without... my solution is long and not elegant. I would not have solved it during an actual exam. There are probably a very fast way to do this (?).

Edited: sorry for the confusion.

Kind regards,

Comment: Are the individual books of the same subject distinguishable? (ie, is picking math book A different from picking math book B?)

Comment: How many books will be selected in total? Four?

Comment: @ Nicholas. The problem does not say anything about this.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the addition principle and multiplication principle.

First, separate the problem into disjoint cases:

Case 1: Choose one math book and one computer science book.

You can choose any of the 8 math books, and regardless of which math book you chose, you can choose any of the 7 computer science books. So, by the multiplication principle, there are $8\times 7$ ways to choose them.

Case 2: Choose one math book and one history book.

There are $8\times 5$ ways to choose them.

Case 3: Choose one computer science book and one history book.

There are $7 \times 5$ ways to choose them.

Finally, by the addition principle, there are $8\times 7 + 8\times 5 + 7\times 5 = 56+40+35=131$ ways to choose the books.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about this!

Answer (score 1):

Using complementary counting we get $${20\choose 2}-{8\choose 2}-{7\choose 2}-{5\choose 2}=...$$

Comment: To be pedantic, that is the total number of ways to take two books minus the number of ways to take two math books minus the number of ways to take two computer science books minus the number of ways to take two history books.

Comment: Thank you @MatthewDaly

Comment: Can you not calculate your self?